# Show that this is equivalent to showing that the probability of U having a decimal expansion ending with repeating 0’s is zero.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1] $. Consider the digits in the decimal expansion of $U$. Show that the probability of $U$ having a decimal expansion ending with repeating 9’s is zero.
Show that this is equivalent to showing that the probability of $U$ having a decimal expansion ending with repeating 0’s is zero.

I got completely lost in this question.May be very new in this measure theoretical course. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

- Show that the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ with decimal expansions ending in repeating nines is countable. What do you know about the measure of countable sets of real numbers?
- Show that if $x\in(0,1)$, then $x$ has a decimal representation ending in repeating nines if and only if it has one ending in repeating zeroes. Example: $0.123999\ldots=0.124000\ldots\;$. In addition, $0$ has a decimal representation ending in repeating zeroes, and $1$ has a decimal representation ending in repeating nines.

Comment: @ Brian the measure of countable set of real numbers is zero.

Comment: @00012suxn: Exactly — and that will give you the desired probability.

Comment: Oh great. Thanks

Comment: @00012suxn: You’re welcome.

Comment: I have another similar question. Let U be uniformly distributed on the interval [13, 17]. Use of  definition find the expected value EU( Expected value of U) @ Brian M

Comment: what does it mean U is uniformly distributed on [a, b]?

Comment: @00012suxn: That’s actually a very different kind of question. Since $U$ is uniformly distributed, its probability density function $f$ is constant: $f(x)=c$ for some real number $c$. What does $c$ have to be? Then by definition $$\Bbb E[U]=\int_{13}^{17}xf(x)\,dx\;.$$ For uniform distribution see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)).

Comment: then It is quit simple. EU will be 60c. Thank you

Comment: @00012suxn: Yes, that looks right; and now all you have to do is work out what value of $c$ actually makes $f$ a probability density function.

Comment: Oh really I thought we are done.Then how ?

Comment: @00012suxn: Use the fact that the probability that $U$ is in the interval $[13,17]$ has to be exactly $1$. That probability is a certain integral involving $f(x)$. You must have somewhere a definition of *probability density function* and a description of its relationship to the probability of $U$ being in a given subset of the domain.

Comment: Show that the set of numbers in [0,1] with  decimal expansions ending in repeating nines is countable. how to show this? @ Brian M

Comment: @00012suxn: Every member of that set except $1=0.999\ldots$ has a decimal expansion of the form $0.d_1\ldots d_n999\ldots$, for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so it can be recovered from the $n$-tuple $\langle d_1,\ldots,d_n\rangle$ of digits. For each $n$ there are only countably many such $n$-tuples (why?), and there are only countably many $n$, so ... ?